# Best way to create a text index on a MongoDB collection via C# driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Using v1.9.0 of the C# driver (latest at time of writing) with MongoDB 2.6.0

What is the best way currently to create a **text index** on a collection, via the C# driver?

From what I could tell, it's not possible via `MongoCollection.CreateIndex`? So currently creating it using MongoDatabase.Eval like so:

`Database.Eval(new EvalArgs { Code = "function(){db.dummycollection.ensureIndex({\"$**\" : \"text\"},{name:\"TextIndex\"});}"`

Am I missing something / is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
collection.EnsureIndex(IndexKeys.Text("a", "b").Ascending("c"), IndexOptions.SetTextLanguageOverride("idioma").SetName("custom").SetTextDefaultLanguage("spanish"));
```

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-874

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/commit/1e7db3bedb3bee1b0ccecdb5f8ff39854526213a

Comment: Cheers. Upvoted for links - very handy. EnsureIndex is being deprecated, between this an @mnemosyn looks exactly what I need. Will try later.

Comment: +1 definitely the cleaner approach. Might be worth noting that it really only works since driver version 1.9.

Comment: Barring EnsureIndex vs CreateIndex difference, this is the route I went down. Specifically: `collection.CreateIndex(IndexKeys.TextAll(), IndexOptions.SetName("TextIndex"));`

Answer (score 5):

Just verified that the following works with the 1.9.0 C# driver and MongoDB 2.6.0-rc2:

```
MongoCollection.CreateIndex(new IndexKeysDocument("Markdown", "text"));
```

(this also works with older drivers)

EDIT

djch's answer shows the better way to do it using the 1.9 driver because it can also be used stronly-typed, e.g.:

```
MongoCollection.CreateIndex(IndexKeys<MyClass>.Text(p => p.Markdown));
```

Comment: Thanks. Will try later and close off

Answer (score 2):

For someone find new answer
I use MongoDB Driver version 2.11.6 and this code work for me

```
var index_test = new CreateIndexModel<CollectionX>(
                Builders<CollectionX>.IndexKeys.Combine(
                    Builders<CollectionX>.IndexKeys.Text(m => m.FieldA),
                    Builders<CollectionX>.IndexKeys.Text(m => m.FieldB)
                ), new CreateIndexOptions()
                {
                    Background = true
                }
            );
CollectionX.Indexes.CreateOne(index_test);
```

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to create indexes in c# is by using the driver wrapper library [MongoDB.Entities](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/MongoDB.Entities). here's an example of creating a text index:

```cs
    DB.Index<Author>()
      .Key(a => a.Name, Type.Text)
      .Key(a => a.Surname, Type.Text)
      .Create();
```

and to do a full-text search, you simply do:

```cs
    DB.SearchText<Author>("search term");
```

it doesn't get any simpler than that :-)