# How do you create a full text search for all text fields in a mongo collection in the c# driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I feel like this should be really simple, yet I've had a google and can't find exactly what I'm looking for.

I can apply the following code in the mongo console:

```
db.collection.createIndex( { "$**": "text" } )
```

and I'll get a full text index on all text fields in my collection. How do I achieve this same result on a given collection in the  **mongo c# driver** ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to create a text index on a MongoDB collection via C# driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23383322/best-way-to-create-a-text-index-on-a-mongodb-collection-via-c-sharp-driver)

Comment: I'm afraid not, two of the answers use code that is now deprecated. The other one has you specify which variables you want the text index to be on. 

The soloution I'm looking for is a full text index which will work on all text fields in a given collection without having to specify them.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a wildcard text index with the following.

```cs
     collection.Indexes.CreateOne(
         new CreateIndexModel<MyType>(
             Builders<MyType>.IndexKeys.Text("$**")));
```